# php curl web service, (using json decode)

Tags: php, json, web-services, curl

I am new in web services, I have created a web service successful and now I want to consume the web service I created, however i am getting a null value after using json decode, I have exected the json_last_error(), and I get 0, I suppose it means no error, can someone explain to me why am getting a null value my request web service is working . below is my code to consume web service.

```
<?php  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){             
$name = isset($_POST['name']);  
$url ="http://localhost/htdocs/my_service/index_rest.php/$name";     // send request resource 
$c = curl_init($url);  //get response   
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true); 
//curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_POST,$data);  
$response = curl_exec($c); 
echo $response;  //decode response 
$result = json_decode($response); 
echo "</br>Data =  : ".$result->data."</br>";  //equals 0, meaning error is none or no json error 
echo json_last_error();  
}  
?>
```

Comment: echo the response and check if it is properly formatted output or not, it should not contain any additional spaces, also verify if it is getting redirected or not

Comment: `var_dump($response);` what is the output?

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = isset($_POST['name']);
```

Is this what you meant to do?
Because you are not storing the value of name just the return of the php isset() language construct.
Maybe you meant?

```
    if(isset($_POST['name'])){
       $name = $_POST['name'];
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your support, I have got the answer sone days ago.

Comment: I mean ..->($url). that you pass to curl_init();  e.g http:localhost/htdocs/folders/.../consumer.php/$fname=$fname; or...add more params of the corresponding provider's ws provider; in this case first name is the param am servicing to get book price.